# How do I properly probe a platform device?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am trying to create a platform driver I have the following code

> Module

```c
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0

#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/pm.h>
#include <linux/of_device.h>
#include <linux/fb.h>

static int simple_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    printk(KERN_ERR "SIMPLE: %s\n", "Probing");
    return 0;
}

const struct of_device_id simple_of_match[] = {
    {
        .compatible = "example,simple",
    },
    { /*End of List*/ },
};

struct platform_driver simple_driver = { 
    .probe = simple_probe,
    .driver = { 
        .name = "simple",
        .owner = THIS_MODULE,
        .of_match_table = simple_of_match 
    }
};

static int __init init(void)
{
    if (platform_driver_register(&simple_driver)) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "SIMPLE: %s\n", "Registerered");
    } else {
        printk(KERN_ERR "SIMPLE: %s\n", "Failed");
    }
    return 0;
}

static void __exit deinit(void)
{
    platform_driver_unregister(&simple_driver);
}

module_init(init);
module_exit(deinit);

MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Simple Platform driver");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Bret Joseph Antonio <bret@binclab.com>");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

My device tree doesn't seem to be running an overlay so the devices status is ok. It is still not running the probe callback.

> DEVICE TREE

```
/dts-v1/;

/ {
    simple@0 {
        compatible = "example,simple";
        pinctrl-names = "lcm_rst_out1_gpio", "lcm_rst_out0_gpio";
        pinctrl-0 = <&PHANDLE1>;
        pinctrl-1 = <&PHANDLE2>;
        status = "okay";
    };
};
```

I am expecting the kernel to register my driver and then  run the probe function but the code

```c
    if (platform_driver_register(&simple_driver) == 0) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "SIMPLE: %s\n", "Registered");
    } else {
        printk(KERN_ERR "SIMPLE: %s\n", "Failed");
    }
```

returns `[    0.178889] SIMPLE: Registered` but the probe function remains silent. What does the probe function depend on?
Shouldn't it run probe as soon as it finds the node in the device tree?

Comment: Like most of the functions in the Linux kernel, `platform_driver_register` returns **0 on success** and negative value (in form of `-<ERROR_CODE>` on fail. Your code swaps these cases and prints "Failed" when the function is actually succeeded.

Comment: If it succeded shouldn't probe also run?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux Kernel Module never reaches ->probe() functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72151808/linux-kernel-module-never-reaches-probe-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *export* your `struct of_device_id simple_of_match[]` to the **of** (Open Firmware) subsystem with a `MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, simple_of_match);` statement.  This will create the required `alias` entry for the module during build time.

Consolation is that other kernel drivers in mainline have been patched for this very same omission, e.g.  [[PATCH] mtd: nand: tango: Export OF device ID table as module aliases](http://www.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-mtd/2017-May/073959.html) and [[PATCH] pwm: samsung: Use MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE() to include OF modalias](https://linux.kernel.narkive.com/ihEWGEFX/patch-pwm-samsung-use-module-device-table-to-include-of-modalias).
That latter patch mentions:

> If the ... driver is built as a module, modalias information is
> not filled so the module is not autoloaded. Use the MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE()
> macro to export the OF device ID so the module contains that information.

That implies that if your driver was always a built-in module rather than a loadable module, then you would not need to have a `MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, simple_of_match);` statement.

---

Convention for kernel code is to declare all symbols as **static** whenever possible. Your code is inconsistent in that regard, i.e. `struct of_device_id simple_of_match[]` and `struct platform_driver simple_driver` are global.

Suggested edits in patch form:

```
- const struct of_device_id simple_of_match[] = {
+ static struct of_device_id simple_of_match[] = {
    {
        .compatible = "example,simple",
    },
    { /*End of List*/ },
  };

+ MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, simple_of_match);


- struct platform_driver simple_driver = { 
+ static struct platform_driver simple_driver = { 
     .probe = simple_probe,
     .driver = { 
         .name = "simple",
         .owner = THIS_MODULE,
         .of_match_table = simple_of_match 
     }
  };
```

Comment: The word “export” is incorrect. `MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE()`does something different to _exporting_.

Comment: Yes that  is what was missing